# How to write wrapper type for several interfaces common to some types

Tags: generics, f#

I want to write some common code for different types withount create one base type for it. Its types implements several interfaces that common code needs. Is it a way or it's not correct for f# type model?

```
type IInterface1 =
    abstract member id :string

type IInterface2 = 
    abstract member weight :float

type A (id, weight) =
    interface IInterface1 with member x.id = id
    interface IInterface2 with member x.weight = weight

type B (id, weight) =
    interface IInterface1 with member x.id = id
    interface IInterface2 with member x.weight = weight

type Common<'T when 'T :> IInterface1 and 'T :> IInterface2> (o :'T) =
    interface IInterface1 with member x.id = o.id
    interface IInterface2 with member x.weight = o.weight

type LBranch<'T> (root :'T) =
    member val root = root
    member val branch = [root] :'T list with get, set
    member x.add item = x.branch <- item :: x.branch; x
    member x.head = match x.branch with h :: _ -> h | _ -> failwith "LevelingTree corrupt"

let a, b = A("1", 10.0), B("2", 100.0)
let ca, cb = Common(a), Common(b)
LBranch(ca).add(cb) // Common<B> is not compatible with Common<A>
```

---

Simple solution what I found isn't good but works:

```
type Common (o :obj) =
    interface IInterface1 with member x.id = match o with :? IInterface1 as o -> o.id | _ -> failwith ""
    interface IInterface2 with member x.weight = match o with :? IInterface2 as o -> o.weight | _ -> failwith ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real simple solution is to have a a complex interface inherit base interfaces, i.e.

```
type IInterface1 =
    abstract member id :string

type IInterface2 = 
    abstract member weight :float

type ICommon =
    inherit IInterface1
    inherit IInterface2
```

Also see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/interfaces#interface-inheritance).